# globally installed npm packages not working

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having problems using globally installed npm packages.
I have confirmed they are installed by using

npm list -g --depth=0

npm bim -g
shows C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm

I am on windows 10.

EDIT:

my npm version is 6.14.15,my node.js version is 16.13.1.
When i download a package from npm, let's say:

npm install nexe -g

the download works. it installs the package in

C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm.
i can confirm that by running

npm list -g --depth=0.

When i want to use any globally installed packages
(for example nexe index.js), I get the message

C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

What do? Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What package is it ? Any error message ? What are the output you mention ? What is the code importing/calling th package ? It's impossible to reproduce your problem from the information you have provided.

Comment: Edited the question, i hope it's clearer... thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not enough.. What does look like the file you are trying to execute ? (the line 1 with that unkown command, which command ?)

Comment: im trying to run a globally installed npm package on a file. Nexe for example should compile a .js file to an .exe. But it's the same for every globally installed package i try to use, another example being nodemon. i navigate to the desired folder via the command line, and use, lets's say, $ nodemon server.js  (which should open server.js with the nodemon module, which automatically updates changes to the file). It's the same with any globally installed package. Locally installed packages work. I dont know how to describe it in more details...

Comment: still havent figured out this one yet...